# how can i reset my automaton in the UPPAAL

Tags: automaton, uppaal

i created some automaton in the UPPAAL model checking tool, and there is a dialog between them. when an error occurs in one of them,other must be reset.
i can't put return edge for all the nodes to go to the start node,because i can't put the guards for all possible errors. 
is there any way to reset the automaton with a function or something like this?
can we go to different nodes without passing the edges? i mean jump from a node to the initial node directly and without using the edges. 
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No.

The closest solution is that the state of the automaton is encoded into variables, then the edges become loops with guards on those variables, and then one can reset those variables with yet another looping edge.